# Google Script: Copy rows from one sheet to another in the same spreadsheet and have the script run at an interval of 25 & 55mins based on local time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently have a script setup that will auto run when i change the loop limit in the code, Need help to modify the script so that instead it runs on a 25min & 55 min interval based on local time. Also need help so that the script will copy the next row below it after the time interval. Sample sheet below that shows how the data is formatted and what to see:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-RlMmNliZIzXoCFk7geycyAjGJGh5laQ2hzhwuJv4tk/edit#gid=842003350

```
// add menu

 function onOpen() { 
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

 ui.createMenu("Auto Trigger")
.addItem("Run","runAuto")
.addToUi();
}


// main function to control workflow - runs once

function runAuto() {

// resets the loop counter if it's not 0

refreshUserProps();

// create trigger to run program automatically

createTrigger();
}


// function to add new log to sheet
// called by trigger once per each iteration of loop

function Record() {

var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1-RlMmNliZIzXoCFk7geycyAjGJGh5laQ2hzhwuJv4tk');
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1-RlMmNliZIzXoCFk7geycyAjGJGh5laQ2hzhwuJv4tk');
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Filtered Raw');

// get the current loop counter

var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var loopCounter = Number(userProperties.getProperty('loopCounter'));

// put some limit on the number of loops
// using a static number in this example

var limit = 1;

// if loop counter < limit number, run the repeatable action

if (loopCounter < limit) {

// see what the counter value is at the start of the loop

Logger.log(loopCounter);

// do stuff
    var date = new Date();
    var stamp = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'Asia/Manila', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var range = ss.getRange('AB:AM').getValues(); 
    var region1 = range[0][0];
    var region2 = range[0][1];
    var region3 = range[0][2];  
    var region4 = range[0][3]; 
    var region5 = range[0][4]; 
    var region6 = range[0][5];
    var region7 = range[0][6];
    var region8 = range[0][7];
    var region9 = range[0][8];
    var region10 = range[0][9];
    var region11 = range[0][10];
    var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Logs'); 
    ts.appendRow([stamp,user,region1 , region2 , region3,region4, region5, region6, region7, region8, region9, region10, region11, 'Logs', 'EMEA']);  

// increment the properties service counter for the loop

loopCounter +=1;
userProperties.setProperty('loopCounter', loopCounter);

// see what the counter value is at the end of the loop
Logger.log(loopCounter);
}

// if the loop counter is no longer smaller than the limit number run this finishing code instead of the repeatable action block

else {
// Log message to confirm loop is finished
//sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue("Finished");
//Logger.log("Finished");

// delete trigger because we've reached the end of the loop
// this will end the program
deleteTrigger();

}
}

// create trigger to run Record every minute
function createTrigger() {

// Trigger every 1 minute
ScriptApp.newTrigger('Record')
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1)
  .create();
}


// function to delete triggers
function deleteTrigger() {

// Loop over all triggers and delete them
var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
}

}

// reset loop counter to 0 in properties
function refreshUserProps() {
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
userProperties.setProperty('loopCounter', 0);
}
```

Comment: What is the issue of your script?

Comment: I answered to your first question considering the running of triggers at intervals. As for the copying the row at the end of the script - please write a separate question and explain more in detail from where to where you want to copy the row.

Comment: For the second part of my question, i would the row that was copied from the Filtered Raw tab to be added to the last row of the Logs tab in the sheet, then the next row in the Filtered Raw tab will be copied then added to the last row of the Logs tab in the sheet. this will run for as long as there is data in the Filtered Raw tab or if it is possible to set a limit in the script

Answer (score 0):

### For running the script at certain times every hour you can use the method [`nearMinute`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#nearMinute(Integer)):

```
function createTrigger() {

 ScriptApp.newTrigger('Record')
 .timeBased()
 .everyHours(1)
 .nearMinute(25)
 .create();

 ScriptApp.newTrigger('Record')
 .timeBased()
 .everyHours(1)
 .nearMinute(55)
 .create();
}
```

However, keep in mind that as the name of the method suggests, the script will be run only approximately at the specified minutes.

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka, i'll test the script you provided and get back to your post after i confirm the results.

Comment: @Tech Enthusiast. Glad to help, hope it worked for you.